# Relação entre as palavras "filho" e "fio"

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, castelhano

É possível notar na língua portuguesa uma certa semelhança entre as palavras "filho" e "fio", tanto na grafia quanto na pronúncia das duas palavras. Inclusive, em pt_BR, a substituição da palavra "filho" por "fio" não é tão incomum, especialmente em um contexto familiar como, por exemplo:

> - Neto: Oi Vó, como vai a senhora?
> - Vó: Vou muito bem, meu 'fio'!

Até aí, nada de mais, poderia ser apenas uma coincidência.

Porém, podemos também notar que a mesma semelhança de grafia e pronúncia ocorre em espanhol (também de origem latina) com as palavras "hijo" (filho) e "hilo"(fio).

Sendo assim, minha dúvida é, existe alguma relação na origem dessas duas palavras ou é tudo apenas uma enorme coincidência?

Comment: `a substituição da palavra "filho" por "fio" não é tão incomum` - isto provavelmente não aconteceria em Portugal, devido à pronúncia diferente.

Comment: Inclui essa informação na pergunta. Obrigado pelo aviso @ANeves

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As duas provêm de palavras latinas muito similares: [filius](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/filius#Latin) no caso de filho, e [filum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/filum#Latin) no caso de fio. Note porém que estas não parecem ter relação entre si, etimologicamente falando, levando a crer que a semelhança não passa de mera coincidência.

Answer (score 2):

A origem das duas palavras já foi bem descrita acima por Amorim.  Acrescento que cada vez menos ouve-se a palavra filho ser pronunciada "fio" por brasileiros alfabetizados. Quando o fazem é geralmente em um tom jocoso.  No entanto,  temos [**quilombos**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quilombo) no Brasil e nesses locais ainda encontramos **quilombolas** que pronunciam "fio".

Comment: Sempre foi e sempre será um uso popular no Brasil. A alfabetização não tem nada que ver, necesariamente. Pode-se considerar linguagem falada.